# Validate C# syntax with C#

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I'm searching for a function (perhaps there is one in the .Net-Framework) which I can use to validate C#-syntax. It can also be a c# parser with build-in validation.

Background: I'm building a little Code-Generator where the user can enter some definitions and gets back full implemented properties etc., but I want to check if the user entered correct C# and if the result is correct, too.

**Edit:**

I **don't want to compile** the code, and it could be uncomplete code. So that for example the User could enter a code-snippet with classes from his code, I don't know, and I only want to validate the syntax, not the 'content'

**Examples**

Input:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.drive("50");
```

Output:

```
Same as input, because it's valid and nothing to do.
```

Input:

```
Car car = new Car()
car.drive("50");
```

Output:

```
Message that it is not valid, beause of missing ';'
```

etc.

I don't know the class `Car` and therefore I can't compile it, I only want to check the syntax.

Comment: C# already has a compiler for itself built-in, which will necessarily validate code that it compiles

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I want to check the syntax from a running c#-program (Code is just in a TextBox), and it won't be compiled by my program

Comment: What's the disadvantage to quickly trying to compile the code?  There's no other 'real' way to determine if it's completely valid.  Unless you try to compile it, you won't know

Comment: @Kieren see my last edit, I can't compile because I don't know the full Code...

Comment: If you don't know the full code, then how can you possibly know if it's valid or not in advance? (You can't)  Without knowing whether `Car` is a type, namespace, variable identifier, type parameter etc, you can't validate the syntax fully.  The snippet might be valid or invalid (syntax-wise).  What then do you mean by 'validate'?

Comment: Well I only mean something like missing ';',  '(|)' etc.

Comment: In that example:  `int myTest = hello;` could be valid or invalid.  `hello` could be a method (so you're missing `(` and `)`) or it could be a variable (in which case, no errors).  Therefore, you can't validate the syntax without knowing which.

Comment: I could give out a warning in cases like this

Comment: Well, you'll have to write it yourself, from scratch, I imagine.  I don't believe there would be any such thing which would call itself a validator while ignoring some syntax rules.

Comment: Ok, I thought so, just wanted to ask ;-), perhaps I'll implement both, the full-compile check for full code, and a little one for uncomplete code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to programatically compile code using the C# compiler:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

..it validates as a part of the compilation process.  You can get the list of errors like this (from the article..surprising since it's a bit messy):

```
foreach(CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
{
 textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
     "Line number " + CompErr.Line + 
     ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber + 
     ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" + 
     Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this .Net class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx

Basically you can call the compiler on the code your looking at and receive back any error messages generated.

Edit: If the code may not compile thats OK, you can look at the error messages returned and ignore stuff like the 'not defined' errors.

You're only other option I think it to write a RegEx that matches the C# language spec.

Comment: Just a comment, such a RegEx I would expect to be several kilobytes long, and not validate fully/correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to cookup some compilable C# code (using [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) or just adding manual snippets around what your users will manually code), and then compile it, as described here: [How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655)